# Can we do screen pinning of android lollipop device without user interaction

Tags: android-screen-pinning

I am trying screen pinning in my app. But in lollipop device before screen pinning and unpinning its asking user interaction. If we click Ok then only screen pinning works.

Is there any way to remove user interaction dialog while pinning the screen?

Comment: If you find out the answer to this question, mind posting it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [`Activity.startLockTask()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startLockTask())